# Finding script associated with Oracle Backup Job

Tags: database, oracle

I am using Oracle Enterprise Manager to view the database jobs scheduled to run. When I look at the task associated with that job, all I see is "Run OS Command". How do I find out what script is being run for the job?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the job definition in the Job Library and the parameters tab in the job.